# How can I create a view with self referencing table and a cyclic condition?

Tags: mysql, view

I have a self-referencing table.

```
ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMAY KEY,
DELETED TIMESTAMP NULL,
PARENT_ID FK
```

How can I create a view of this table which each row's `DELETED` is `NULL` and any of its parent's `DELETED` is also `NULL`?

So far, I tried and it doesn't work as expected.

```
CREATE VIEW `OPERATOR_` AS
SELECT c.* from OPERATOR AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN OPERATOR AS p ON c.PARENT_ID = p.ID
WHERE c.DELETED_ IS NULL AND p.DELETED_ IS NULL;
```

### example 1

```
ID    DELETED   PARENT_ID
0     2017...   NULL         NOT SELECTED
1     NULL      0            NOT SELECTED
2     NULL      1            NOT SELECTED
```

### example 2

```
ID    DELETED   PARENT_ID
0     NULL      NULL             SELECTED
1     2017...   0            NOT SELECTED
2     NULL      1            NOT SELECTED
```

### example 3

```
ID    DELETED   PARENT_ID
0     NULL      NULL             SELECTED
1     NULL      0                SELECTED
2     2017...   1            NOT SELECTED
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    FROM tbl a
    WHERE deleted IS NULL
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tbl 
                       WHERE id = a.parent_id
                         AND deleted IS NULL );
```

See if that works, then turn it into a `VIEW`.